# Remote branches are no longer being tracked

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

We're using `SourceTree` to create our feature branches and push local code up to our repos in BitBucket. In the past two weeks we have started getting errors in Jenkins when switching branches.

Investigating the error leads to an error from Git about tracking not being setup:

> There is no tracking information for the current branch

This has now happened for feature branches from **3** different developers. I am thinking an update to SourceTree perhaps caused some setup change locally where branches are no longer being tracked on creation.

Looking through older questions on SO, this seems different due to no active changes being made in our local dev enviornments.

I tested creating a new feature locally and pushed it. When I switched code manually I did not get any tracking errors, which seems to further indicate a setup issue.

If anyone is knowledge on SourceTree or default Git options for tracking, or have insight on why those options may have been changed or reset, I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: This sounds much more like a change on Jenkins' side and one of more scripts you are running that assume Jenkins has checked out the branch with an upstream defined...

Comment: The error about tracking is reported by Git itself when running from the command line.